# Large amount of whitespace between figure and text. Using vspace doesn't work

Tags: floats, includegraphics, white-space

I have the following figure:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = \columnwidth]{figures/fig.pdf}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:pipeline}
\end{figure}
```

There is a large amount of whitespace between the figure and the text below it. I tried the following to fix it:

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = \columnwidth]{figures/fig.pdf}
    \vspace{-0.2in}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:pipeline}
    \vspace{-0.3in}
\end{figure}
```

But this doesn't really do anything except add more whitespace between some of my paragraphs lower in the page which is odd. I decrease the second vspace so that it's at -0.4 in and it works. But -0.4 is too big of a decrease and results in the text below overlapping with the caption. If I try to increase it to any value greater than -0.4 (to -0.39 for instance), I get the same problem as before with a large amount of whitespace. I don't get what I am doing wrong? I have used this same code for other figures and it worked. The only thing that's different is the pdf which is much wider.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. i guess you have a twoside document and you content is flushbottom. Make it raggedbottom.

Comment: mov the -4 outside the fig environ

Comment: Hi @justan0thelurker and welcome to TeX-SE, could you please provide a MWE. Without knowing the class and other configurations you are using, we can only guess what is going on.

Comment: Whitespace could be part of the image itself, not just inserted between the elements. If you use `\fbox{\includegraphics[..]{...}}`, what do you see?

Comment: @Johannes_B - Is partly right.  If using negative \vspace just moves the gap elsewhere, the problem is caused by what is at the top of the next page and should be at the bottom of this page but doesn't fit.

Comment: Do please tell us which document class you employ -- and which options (if any) you set at the `\documentclass` stage.

Comment: Sorry for the lacking information, I'm still very new to Latex

I tried raggedbottom and that worked. Thank you @Johannes_B

The whitespace isn't from the pdf itself (confirmed using \fbox). Moving the -4 outside of the fig environment also didn't work.